# Mysterious photo uploads to Google Photos

Tags: macos, photos, google-sync

I realise this question is somewhat of an intersection of OS X and Google but I'll start here. My partner discovered that most of her pictures (up to 2013) that are on her Mac were mysteriously available on Google Photos; we're puzzled as to how all these pictures ended up on Google Photos when we did not explicitly upload them.

What mechanisms are available that would automatically sync up photos from OS X? My prime suspect is Google Drive for OS X. We don't appear to have that installed any more and that might explain why the pics only go to 2013.

What other items can we look at? They're not pictures from her phone (iPhone 4, iOS 7) nor have we installed anything on there that might sync pics from her phone.

Comment: All those online storage apps sneak in a "Do you want me to look after your photos too?" query at some point. It's a good way of getting you to use up your storage space & have to buy more. "Ooh, that's a good idea" only needs one click, then you forgot you ever did it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it turned out to be a blogger.com blog storing photos in the Google Photos account. We had assumed the blogger account would use it's own photo store.

Bottom line: Google uses Google Photos for general photo storage for many of its services.

Answer (score 0):

[Google + for iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/google+/id447119634?mt=8), [Google Photos for iOS and Google Photo Autobackup](https://photos.google.com/apps) do that. The age of the pictures is not really relevant, because the last app would upload any image on your computer (on the pictures folders mostly). 
Also, Picasa used to be able to sync your pics with G+, although I'm not sure it was automatic.

Comment: Thanks for the info! In the end it ended up being her linked blogger.com account that was actually storing items in Google Photos which we did not realise. If you want to add that to the list above I'll accept your answer.

Comment: Thanks Fred, I think it may be better if you describe exactly how the blogger.com was linked and uploading pics as an answer, and accept it. Mine could be an alternative list of places to look at.